get disk information using PowerShell
I'm trying to query disk information on Windows using PowerShell. I need to return Drive Letter, friendly name and PNPDeviceID. I've written the following but in some scenarios the wrong PNPDeviceID is returned for SD cards, it seems Win32_DiskDrive finds the generic storage device rather than the accutal device ID of the SD Card. Is there a way for me to get all the information I need without using Win32_DiskDrive or can it be done without using WMI at all?
$USBDevices = @()
$Win32DiskDrives = Get-CimInstance win32_diskdrive | Where { $_.MediaType -ne 'Fixed hard disk media' -and $null -ne $_.Size }
   
ForEach ($Win32DiskDrive in $Win32DiskDrives ) { 
    $DriveLetter = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($Win32DiskDrive.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"  |`
        ForEach-Object { Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition" } | ForEach-Object { $_.deviceid }

    If ($null -ne $DriveLetter -and $DriveLetter -ne $env:SystemDrive) {

        $USBDevices += [PSCustomObject] [Ordered] @{ 
            DriveLetter = $DriveLetter
            PNPDeviceID = $($Win32DiskDrive.PNPDeviceID)
            Caption     = $Win32DiskDrive.Caption
        }
    }
}


have you tried Get-Disk to see if it outputs what you're after?

Get-Disk does, how can I get the pnpdeviceID from there?

Seems like the PNPID is embedded in the Path property when using Get-Disk.  You can use a Regex or some other string manipulation to pull it from there.  Note that Get-Disk uses WMI under the covers, so if you're hoping to avoid it all together, you're out of luck.

Unfortunately path isn’t always the pnpdeviceID

perhaps an approach with Get-Disk chained with Get-PnpDevice. It's a little hard going off guesses since we can't see what you're after and what's not happening

You could try using the following command which returns the PNPDeviceID as well as its FriendlyName:
$Name = Get-Disk | % {$_.FriendlyName}

Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName $Name

To get the drive letter you can try using this command that returns the Drive Letter and the Name assigned to this drive letter:
Get-Volume | Select-Object DriveLetter,FileSystemLabel

I hope I solve your doubt!
